# How to add the checked item in listView to ArrayList?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, getview

I have a ListView with 12 items each item contains a TextView and a checkbox. I managed to keep the CheckBox check status persistent so that when I scroll up and down I do not lose the check status set to each CheckBox.

The problem I am facing now is, for each item in the ListView I want to add the TextView to an ArrayList if its correspondeing CheckBox is checked, and if the corresponding CheckBox is unchecked, I should delete the TextView from the ArrayList if it is contained in it.

In the below code of the getView() method, the line "Log.d(TAG, "chosen topic size: " + chosenTopics.size());" always returns zero??!!

please help me to solve this issue.

**getView()**:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvlist_topic);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbList_hook);
        holder.iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivList_delete);

        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ItemDesign element = (ItemDesign) holder.cb.getTag();
                element.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());

                if(element.isChecked()) {
                    if (!chosenTopics.contains(designList.get(position).getTopic()))
                        chosenTopics.add(designList.get(position).getTopic());
                }

                if (!element.isChecked()) {
                    if (!chosenTopics.isEmpty()) {
                    if (chosenTopics.contains(designList.get(position).getTopic()))
                        chosenTopics.remove(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "chosen topic size: " + chosenTopics.size());
        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.cb.setTag(designList.get(position));

    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).cb.setTag(designList.get(position));
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.tv.setText(designList.get(position).getTopic());
    holder.cb.setChecked(designList.get(position).isChecked());

    holder.iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (holder.cb.isChecked())
                holder.cb.setChecked(false);

            designList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**LogCat errors after moving initialisation of the ArrayList into the constructor**:

```
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500): Process:  
com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02, PID: 22500
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500):   
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500):    at 
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500):    at 
java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
02-12 14:40:14.117: E/AndroidRuntime(22500):    at
```

com.example.mqtt_designlayout_02.listviewadapter.ListViewAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(ListViewAdapter.java:95)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getView() method, the line "Log.d(TAG, "chosen topic size: " +
>   chosenTopics.size());" always returns zero??!!

Because initializing `chosenTopics` ArrayList inside `getView` method so when ListView is scrolling up/down `chosenTopics` object is initializing again. depend on how many times getView method is called.

To fix issue move

```
this.chosenTopics = new ArrayList<String>();
```

line inside constructor of Adapter

Comment: getView() will be called when you scroll the list. so initialize the arraylist inside you constructor and use that object to set the widgets

Comment: ok, but now i receive "index ut of bound exception" on this line "chosenTopics.remove(position);"  please see logcat errors posted above

Comment: @Kantesh: Instead of `holder.cb.setTag(designList.get(position));` Pass only `position` as `holder.cb.setTag(position);` and get position inside `onCheckedChanged` like `int clickedPostion=Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString())` now use  `clickedPostion` for getting `ItemDesign` from `designList` and use  `clickedPostion` for remove